# Issue with RegEx lookaround where new lines are included

Tags: regex, find, sublimetext2

**Edit**: Clarification, I am using Sublime text. It appears the problem was in fact the multiline issue. Thank you all for your feedback!

Okay so I'm trying to analyze text blocks similar to this:

```
Private Sub NAV_VE124_Click()
    'Open the picture in its description field
    Call ShowPic(Me.NAV_VE124.Description)
End Sub
```

and the regex pattern `(?<=Private Sub )((.*?)(?=_Click))`

seems to work to locate `NAV_VE124`

and yet for some reason `(?<=\')((.*?)(?=End))`

Does not produce any result...

Also, I would like to combine these two searches so that I only grab the stuff after `'` if the other condition is allowed, so any thoughts on how to do that would also be phenomenal.

Comment: Do you have multiline flag on?

Comment: [`^Private Sub(.+?)(?=_Click).*\R\s+'(?s)(.+?)(?=End)(?s-)`](https://regex101.com/r/bH5qV7/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\')((.|\s)*(?=End))
```

the problem is the multiline...not sure what regex tool your using but just do a (.|\s)* to match anything including newline. If \s doesn't work then find out what matches newline for your tool.

Comment: Make the quantifier lazy, otherwise: https://regex101.com/r/bH5qV7/2

Comment: This seems to work in regex101.com emulator but not in Sublime. Thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: Don't use `(.|\s)`, it's *extremely* inefficient, as this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH5qV7/3) shows.  (It should fail, but it times out instead--and switching to a lazy quantifier doesn't help.)  Most flavors/tools support a single-line/DOTALL mode that lets the dot match newlines, and Sublime Text is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex engine supports it, you could come up with:

```
^Private Sub(.+?)(?=_Click).*\R\s+'(?s)(.+?)(?=End)(?s-)
```

Tested with Sublime as well.

Comment: Hmm.. I get an error that "Hexadecimal escape sequence was invalid"