# Regex Search Patterns Select:(This1)and(This2 but only if This1 is Found)

Tags: regex, recursion, find

EDIT: I believe the solution I'm looking for here is with recursion.

With regards to this [Issue with RegEx Lookaround where new lines are included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347226/issue-with-regex-lookaround-where-new-lines-are-included?noredirect=1#comment58404347_35347226)

I am trying to find a way to search a section of text for a header, and then select a section of the header, as well as a specific part of the section below it, which also requires a small conditional search.

The text format is like this:

```
Private Sub NAV_VE124_Click()
    'Open the picture in its description field
    Call ShowPic(Me.NAV_VE124.Description)
End Sub
```

And I would like to select `VE124 Open the picture in its description field`.

Or, more generally, I want everything between `NAV_` and `Click()`, and everything from the `'` to the `Call` (not the line break as some of the descriptions have more than one line of text).

Any thoughts or help would be hugely appreciated. I have about 20000 of these to catalog so I'm kind of at a loss for how else to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this should do it:

```
.*NAV_(.*)Click\(\)((?:\r\n\s*'(?:[^\r\n]*))*)(?:\r\n^((?!Sub NAV_).)*)*
```

Let me know if any of my assumptions are incorrect.

- we don't care about the stuff before the first NAV_ (you may want to check for Sub though)

  - .*
- we want to find the literal NAV_

  - NAV_
- we want to find anything that is before Click() and capture it (we can just look for anything that isn't a space since there will be a space after Click() and we will match the Click() later)

  - ([^\s]*)
- we want to match Click() (you may want to only match the opening ( in case there are params)

  - Click\(\)
- now things get interesting, I'll break these bits up

  - ((?:\r\n\s*'(?:[^\r\n]*))*)

    - \r\n\s*' this bit gets the newline and the single quote that starts a comment
    - (?:[^\r\n]*) this bit gets all the comment text (anything other then a newline
    - the * at the end allows multiple comment lines
    - the outer parentheses capture the bit we're interested in
- now we just ignore everything else until the next Sub NAV_ (using lookahead)

  - (?:\r\n^((?!Sub NAV_).)*)*

Given that you appear to be pulling comments from VB code maybe look at tools like doxygen/castle windsor to see if they can help. If I have missed something in the question you may find this starts to get beyond a regular language and needs something other than a regex.

Edit: finished off the partially complete regex

Comment: Hmm... while this seems like it should be right it appears to select the full line including `Private Sub` and `Nav`

It also does not select the text after `'`

Comment: Ok. I've tested using Notepad++ (using 'Wrap around' and not '. matches newline) and replacing that full regex with `$1$2\r\n` and I get the list of methods with their comments. Maybe the newline character isn't matching correctly or the tool you're using doesn't match Notepad++. I'd try Notepad++ and \n instead of \r\n.

Comment: Also... it will still match the full line including `Private Sub` but the replace will ignore that and only use the 2 groups.